# How can I restore SQL Server database to a custom location, if the backup file was renamed?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Suppose I have an SQL Server database called `bubu` and the respective backup file is `bubu.bak`.

If I want to restore it with the backing store in a custom location, I use the following T-SQL statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE "bubu2" FROM DISK = N'C:\bubu.bak' WITH REPLACE, STATS = 10, 
    MOVE N'bubu' TO N'C:\custom\bubu.mdf', MOVE N'bubu_log' TO N'C:\custom\bubu.LDF'
```

And so I have a new database `bubu2`, which happens to be the backup copy of `bubu`. The important thing here is that I assume that the backup contains the logical files `bubu` and `bubu_log`, because the backup file is named `bubu.bak`.

Now, suppose someone renames `bubu.bak` to `mumu.bak`. Doing so, breaks my logic, since now I will try this T-SQL statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE "mumu2" FROM DISK = N'C:\mumu.bak' WITH REPLACE, STATS = 10, 
    MOVE N'mumu' TO N'C:\custom\mumu.mdf', MOVE N'mumu_log' TO N'C:\custom\mumu.LDF'
```

And of course, I fail, because `mumu.bak` does not contain the logical files `mumu` and `mumu_log` - renaming the backup file does not rename the logical files contained in the backup (of course).

But then, how do I do what I need if the backup file was renamed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [filelistonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx) option to retrieve the files names in a backup:

```
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\mumu.bak'
```

Comment: This gives a rowset with many columns. Can I select the  columns to fetch?

Comment: You could use [insert ... exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511502/sql-server-restore-filelistonly-resultset) to store the results in a temporary table.  Then you can select a few columns from that.  Lot of code though.

Comment: OK, another question - is it guaranteed that the first row corresponds to the mdf file? Or better yet, can I fetch just the MDF file name from the backup?

Comment: Not sure, but if you use the `insert ... exec` solution, you can filter for the MDF filename.